# Why is this throwing up an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a jquery json ajax call and inside my success function I have the following check:

```
if(data['error'] === 1) {

    $return_feedback.html(data['error_msg']);

}
```

For some reason I can't seem to understand though right now, I'm getting an error:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null'
```

And refers to the if(data['error'] line of code above.

So I've looked at what my script is returning and it is true - there is no data. But then shouldn't it just skip this if statement altogether? Or am I supposed to check if the data value exists first before calling an if statement?

Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data is null

use this:

```
if (!data){
    //throw exception or handle the problem
}
else if(data['error'] === 1) {
    $return_feedback.html(data['error_msg']);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should check if data is truthy first:

```
if(data && data['error'] === 1) {

    $return_feedback.html(data['error_msg']);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, which should work without errors:

```
if(typeof data!=='undefined' && data['error'] === 1) {
```